# Is expected value distributive?

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

For example:
If P1 and P2 are exponential pdf's, with λ1 = 1, and λ2 = 2

$$P(X=x) = P^1(x) + P^2(x) - P^1(x)P^2(x)$$

We know E[Y] where Y follows an exponential distribution is $$1/λ$$

Would the expected value be:
$$E[X] = 1/1 + 1/2 - (1/1)(1/2) = 1$$

Comment: Expected value is _linear_: $E[aX+bY]=aE[X]+bE[Y]$ for _any_ random variables $X$ and $Y$ and any constants $a$ and $b$. But it does not always distribute across products. $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are _uncorrelated_. A sufficient condition for $X$ and $Y$ to be uncorrelated is for them to be _independent_ (though this is not necessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the expectation operator is linear.  It does not distribute

In this case, *if* $P_X(x)=P_1(x)+P_2(x)-P_1(x)P_2(x)$ where $P_1, P_2$ are exponential probability *density* functions with parameters $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ respectively, then:

I : $\lambda_1\lambda_2=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ is required for this to be a valid probability density function.

$$\int_{\Bbb R^+} P_X(x)\operatorname d x ~=~2-\dfrac{\lambda_1\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}$$

$$\lambda_2= \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1-1}, \quad \lambda_1 > 1$$

II : The Expectation is:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X) ~=~& \int_{\Bbb R^+} x~P(X=x)~\mathrm d~ x \\[1ex] =~& \int_{\Bbb R^+} x(P_1(x)+P_2(x)-P_1(x)P_2(x))~\mathrm d~ x\\[1ex]~ = ~& \frac 1{\lambda_1}+\frac 1{\lambda_2}-\int_{\Bbb R^+} x\lambda_1\lambda_2e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)x}~\mathrm d~ x \\[1ex] ~=~ & \frac 1{\lambda_1}+\frac 1{\lambda_2}-\frac{\lambda_1\lambda_2}{(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^2} \\[1ex] =~& 1-\lambda_1^{-1}+\lambda_1^{-2}\end{align}$$